# Django Allauth Facebook login send me to "login cancelled" page

Tags: python, django, allauth

I am making an app in Django and using the allauth library to enable Facebook login. I set up everything accordingly in my Django project and the FB Developer console (I am pretty sure of this because my Google login works), but when I click on the "Login with Facebook button", a popup window appears with a Facebook page asking me to login, but my app is already in the login cancelled page in the following URL: "https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/accounts/social/login/cancelled/". If I login in the popup window nothing changes in my app and the popup just closes. The weirdest thing is that I am not getting any error or warning logs.

This happens both in development and production mode. I read in other posts that adding "ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'" in settings.py can solve the issue, but it did not work for me.

Has anyone had a similar problem and know the solution to this?